# Gradient function for log-likelihood

Tags: logistic, likelihood, gradient

We are trying to calculate the gradient for a logistic regression where the log-likelihood function is:

$$ll(x,y,\beta)=ln\left(\frac{\Pi {(e^{x_i\beta}})^{y_i}}{\Sigma {e^{x_i\beta}}}\right)$$

$x$ is a $c\times v$ matrix containing independent variable information. $x_i$ is the $i$th row of the $x$ matrix and corresponds to a specific data observation.

$y$ is a vector of length $c$ containing the dependent variable information on a normalized scale (sum is 1.0). $y_i$ is the corresponding response to the observation $x_i$.

$\beta$ is a vector of length $v$ which are the coefficients we are trying to maximize with the gradient in a Newtonian method.

We have tried to derive the first and second derivatives to get the gradient function, but it's above my linear algebra skills.  I apologize if this is already available, but I did not find it when I looked around.

Comment: 1. You can (helpfully) simplify that expression first. 2. my first attempt at a search of what you're asking about: [*logistic regression derivative of log likelihood*](https://www.google.com/search?q=logistic+regression+derivative+of+log+likelihood) turns up useful hits right at the top of the page, like [Cosma Shalizi's lovely notes](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/12/lectures/ch12.pdf), see eq 12.11 and 12.12 and the simplifications of $\log\mathcal{L}$ above those). You should be able to reproduce equivalent simplifications of the log likelihood in your formulation

Comment: [Another](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/pdfs/40%20LogisticRegression.pdf) of the topmost hits on the above search has a similar derivation on p2, and tells you which precise steps it takes as it goes through the derivation

Comment: Downvoted this.  It appears you got some very timely and relevant comments from @Glen_b, but then abandon the question after posting it. Also, this seems more suited for [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as this is fundamentally _how to do a derivative_.